# Memoise a function taking a function as argument

Tags: r, memoization, memoise

I want to do some memoization using the `R` package `memoise` on the following function taking as argument a function:

```
library(memoise)

func      = function(x) x
slowFunc  = function(a,f,b=2) {Sys.sleep(1); a+b}
quickFunc = memoise(slowFunc)

> system.time(slowFunc(2, func, 3))
   user  system elapsed 
      0       0       1 
> system.time(slowFunc(2, func, 3))
   user  system elapsed 
   0.00    0.00    0.99
```

There are two successive calls and the second returns 1 sec on the timing whereas I could have expected something instantaneous.

It is weird but it seems `memoise` do not apply when arguments are functions ... how the function is represented in the memory to have this working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code doesn't use the memoized function. It calls the original function which results in a 1 second sleep.

If you try with `system.time(quickFunc(2, func, 3))` you'll see that there is no delay the second time.

`memoise` works *only*  with function arguments, and returns a function that either returns the cached value, or calls the input function to create it. While

```
m<-memoise(5)
```

won't raise an error, trying to call it (eg with `m(5)`) will return an the following error

```
Error in mm() : could not find function "f"
```

You can check the function's code by simply typing `memoise`. The result

```
function (f) 
{
    cache <- new_cache()
    memo_f <- function(...) {
        hash <- digest(list(...))
        if (cache$has_key(hash)) {
            cache$get(hash)
        }
        else {
            res <- f(...)
            cache$set(hash, res)
            res
        }
    }
    attr(memo_f, "memoised") <- TRUE
    return(memo_f)
}
```

shows that `memoise` creates a hash of all the arguments and uses it as the key to an in-memory cache, even if these are functions.

Comment: right, there is a typo but mostly my atomic example did not reproduced a more complicated case. Thanks for the answer anayway.